# Custom checkboxes with checkbox under text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have custom inline checkboxes with the text aligned above the checkbox. The checkbox has to be horizontally centered compared to the text. It should look like this:

[image]

I have tried to add the `<br/>` tag and moved the text over the control like this:

```
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Check this custom checkbox</span>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
  </label>
```

without success... you can see the [failed plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NvCREEytP61Se9yvhLQn?p=preview).

[This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W3uWM6jk00CgBDZ7Hjrc?p=preview) is the normal inline checkboxes of bootstrap v4

Comment: you can try with table for achieve this....

Comment: @Mahesh I've thought about it... the problem is to make the text "clickable" (which is the case with custom checkboxes). Also the table is less flexible when resizing the screen. I want my checkboxes to use multiple lines when it can't fit the width of the screen

Comment: @Mahesh Never use tables for layout, that's very bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.custom-checkbox {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}
.custom-control-indicator {
  position: static; /* override _custom-forms.scss */
}
```

... will do the trick, if I understand your request correctly. However, the text and the checkboxes are "*vertically*" aligned, not *"horizontally"*.

```css
.custom-checkbox {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}
.custom-control-indicator {
  position: static; /* needed to override position:absolute; from 
                     * _custom-forms.scss - bootstrap 
                     */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Check 1</span>
  </label>
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Check 2</span>
  </label>
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Check 3</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW this might have issues in IE and will simply not work at all in IE9 or earlier.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! But when I add your css to my plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/T0EVJeeDQnb4R1EbkI3V?p=preview), it doesn't work :(

Comment: @DavidG thanks for mentioning it! I'm fine with this restriction

Comment: @ncohen, that's because you use `_custom-forms.scss`, which adds `position:absolute` to `.custom-control-indicator`. Add `.custom-control-indicator {position:static;}` and it will work.

Comment: Do you use bootstrap v4 in your snippet? Can you please send a full plunker, I can't reproduce it!

Comment: That's perfect! Can you please add that to your answer?

Comment: @DavidG. The total current internet traffic using IE9 is `0.02%`. And it's all just website owners checking if their website works in IE9. *Nobody* uses that browser for browsing. Not even Microsoft, as they [dropped support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support) for it since 2016.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu If you're building a website for general public, then yes, you can ignore that. However, if you're building for a specific audience (e.g. hospitals, schools, enterprise customers) then that percentage can increase dramatically, sometimes right up to 100%.

Comment: @DavidG, `0.02%` of web traffic and *no longer supported by manufacturer* is, by all means, an exceptional case. Any and all exceptional cases should be clearly specified in the request when asked on [so]. [`flexbox`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is *only* supported in 97.59%  of current web browsers. IE9 and below, Netscape Navigator and, in general, browser versions developed prior to 2015 do not support it. Consider using `<table>` for those versions.

Comment: Note [`box-shadow`](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow/embed) currently has less browser support than flexbox. If you're using `box-shadow`, you should probably consider using flexbox as well.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I wasn't really disagreeing with you, just saying that it's important to recognise that some industries (for better or worse) work to different standards than the vast majority. It's all about your target audience in the end, and some people have no choice. I have a friend who still has to support IE6 (personally I would kill myself before doing that, but he seems happy!) As for the `box-shadow` comment, yes, but a missing shadow is going to be a lot less apparent than having a completely messed up layout.

Comment: @David, I find myself supporting browsers I really think I shouldn't more often than not, mostly for the same type of clients as mentioned by you, above. Note flexbox not working in the case above defaults to `display:inline` (or `inline-block` - from Bootstrap), which results into misalignment. The markup would remain accessible and usable. In principle, it's about aspect, so it's as severe as `box-shadow` not applying. Sorry if my comments above sound harsh. I'm only trying to be clear so I don't get misunderstood. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

try this code......

```
<label for='chkCart'>Add to Cart</label><br>
<input type='checkbox' id='chkCart'/>
```

in your jquery script...

```
$(function () {
    $("#chkCart").click(function () {
        var lbl = $("label[for='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']");
        lbl.text($(this).is(":checked")?"Added":"Add to Cart");
    });
});
```